# Twisted TLS Server offering no shared ciphers

Tags: python, ssl, twisted

I built a TLS server with Python Twisted (17.5.0), running on python 3.5.3 with the following code (its shortened):

```
from OpenSSL import crypto
from twisted.internet.ssl import (PrivateCertificate,KeyPair,Certificate)
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet import protocol, task, defer

pkey_obj = open("server.key","rb").read()
pkey = crypto.load_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, pkey_obj)


regsrv_obj = open("servercert.pem","rb").read()
regsrv_cert = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, regsrv_obj)

certificate = Certificate(regsrv_cert)
prkey = KeyPair(pkey)
prkey_and_cert = PrivateCertificate.fromCertificateAndKeyPair(certificate, prkey)

tls_server_options = prkey_and_cert.options()

factory = protocol.Factory.forProtocol(Echo)
reactor.listenSSL(5444, factory, tls_server_options)
return defer.Deferred()
```

I adapted it from http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/ssl.html

The server starts correctly with the following commands and is available:

> python3 tls_server.py

If now want to query this server with *openssl s_client* the server outputs the following error:

> [Failure instance: Traceback: : [('SSL routines', 'tls_post_process_client_hello', 'no shared cipher')]

Question: Why do server and client cannot agree on a common cipher?

The server's key is an EC-key based on secp521r1 and if I open an TLS server with the server's key/cert by *openssl s_server* it works perfectly. It must be something wrong with my twisted implementation.

Edit:
I tried to enumerate the available ciphers at server side with

> nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 5444 localhost

But it seems like the server doesn't provide any ciphers nor SSL capability. This is the error I get on server side if I output the error in die connectionLost() method of the underlaying twisted protocol:

```
2017-08-15 15:35:40+0200 [-] connection lost: [Failure instance: Traceback: <class 'OpenSSL.SSL.Error'>: [('SSL routines', 'tls_post_process_client_hello', 'no shared cipher')]
2017-08-15 15:35:40+0200 [-] /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py:597:_doReadOrWrite
2017-08-15 15:35:40+0200 [-] /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py:208:doRead
2017-08-15 15:35:40+0200 [-] /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py:214:_dataReceived
2017-08-15 15:35:40+0200 [-] /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/twisted/protocols/tls.py:315:dataReceived
2017-08-15 15:35:40+0200 [-] --- <exception caught here> ---
2017-08-15 15:35:40+0200 [-] /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/twisted/protocols/tls.py:235:_checkHandshakeStatus
2017-08-15 15:35:40+0200 [-] /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py:1716:do_handshake
2017-08-15 15:35:40+0200 [-] /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py:1456:_raise_ssl_error
2017-08-15 15:35:40+0200 [-] /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py:54:exception_from_error_queue
2017-08-15 15:35:40+0200 [-] ]
```

Comment: Can you use [sslscan](https://github.com/rbsec/sslscan) to check which ciphers your server does accept? That should help narrow down the issue.

Comment: Can I use another tool instead of sslscan, as this has is quite cumbersome to install?

Comment: https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ssl-enum-ciphers.html

Comment: I performed a nmap scan, please see the result above

Comment: Does it work when you use `twisted.internet.ssl.DefaultOpenSSLContextFactory()` as the third parameter for `listenSSL()`? Are you sure `prkey_and_cert.options()` returns a context factory? I can't find any documentation to support that.

Comment: you're right, it's working with DefaultOpenSSLContextFactory(). But I'm a little bit confused now since the example on http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/16.3.0/core/howto/ssl.html for TLS echo server suggests a method like I my code was.

Comment: Might be a bug with the first example. The second example there puts those options in `factory.options = cert.options()`